# PHP does not insert in mySQL in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a `string array` and I am trying to insert each data in this array into `mySQL` inside a `foreach` loop. But I recognized It doesn't insert all of them. Sometimes insert all, sometimes insert some of them. My code is below. Please let me figure out what my problem here is.

```
foreach($cbarray as $chvalue){
     list($kid, $odemeopt) = explode('-',$chvalue);
     $i_tr="trp".$kid;
     $i_en="enp".$kid;
     $i_fr="frp".$kid;

    $tr_kargop=doubleval($_POST[$i_tr]);
    $en_kargop=doubleval($_POST[$i_en]);
    $fr_kargop=doubleval($_POST[$i_fr]);                                                            

    if($odemeopt==1){
        $ik_tr="trk".$kid;
        $ik_en="enk".$kid;
        $ik_fr="frk".$kid;                          
    }
    $tr_kargoextra=doubleval($_POST[$ik_tr]);
    $en_kargopextra=doubleval($_POST[$ik_en]);
    $fr_kargopextra=doubleval($_POST[$ik_fr]);                                                              

$myquery = "INSERT INTO item_kargo(product_id,kargo_id,kargo_priceTR,kargo_priceEN,kargo_priceFR,odemefarkiTR,odemefarkiEN,odemefarkiFR) VALUES ('$next_increment','$kid','$tr_kargop','$en_kargop','$fr_kargop','$tr_kargoextra','$en_kargopextra','$fr_kargopextra')";
   echo "<h2>".$myquery."</h2>";

   $kargo_bilgisi=mysql_query($myquery) or die("!!hata kargooo :".mysql_error());
 }
```

This is the result of `myquery`

```
INSERT INTO item_kargo(product_id,kargo_id,kargo_priceTR,kargo_priceEN,kargo_priceFR,odemefarkiTR,odemefarkiEN,odemefarkiFR) VALUES ('4','1','1','1','1','','','')

INSERT INTO item_kargo(product_id,kargo_id,kargo_priceTR,kargo_priceEN,kargo_priceFR,odemefarkiTR,odemefarkiEN,odemefarkiFR) VALUES ('4','2','2','2','2','','','')

INSERT INTO item_kargo(product_id,kargo_id,kargo_priceTR,kargo_priceEN,kargo_priceFR,odemefarkiTR,odemefarkiEN,odemefarkiFR) VALUES ('4','4','3','3','3','3','3','3')
```

Comment: can you echo the query before run it and print it here?

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` after the query to see, if something went wrong (which here it obviously does). Besides you should have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli), as `mysql_x` is deprecated.

Comment: What are the values of `$next_increment` and `$cbarray`?

Comment: $next_increment is last inserted row id of another table which i need it here.  $cbarray is kepping some value caming from some checkbox and input text field. I tested them all. They are coming there properly. just mysql_query doesnt work sometimes in that loop

Comment: Check if any `NOT NULL` column in `item_kargo` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If can't you get your error from mysql_error() you can "echo" your data with var_dump(), so you can see how your array is build up. This helps me often to figure out my error in some loops.